# File and Text data submission using JQuery Ajax with PHP on the server side.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have looked into many posts on this subject so please do not mark it as duplicate as there are no straight answers provided. But if you truly believe that I may have missed something, which provides cross-browser support (IE8+ too) do indicate which one and then mark it as duplicate.

I want to use JQuery AJAX to post files and some text data and access that info in PHP on the server side using `$_FILES` and `$_POST`. I am able to do so without AJAX. The problem is when I start using AJAX.

Here is a simple example:

HTML:

```
  <form id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="text"/>
       <input type="file"/>
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
   var ser_data = $('#upload_form').serialize();

 ...on submit... {
 ...
   upload_promise = $.ajax({
    url: 'upload1.php',  
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'POST',
    data: ser_data,
   });
 ...
  }
```

Well, we all know that `.serialize` will serialize only the text fields input and file is not readable by JS, etc. I am not trying to do anything fancy here. I just need a mechanism to access `$_FILES` and `$_POST` in PHP on the server side with the file name and the text data entered on the client side. The actual form has more fields (more file and text types) but this is the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send files and post data trough ajax, you should use a FormData object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

```
var fd = new FormData();

var myFileInput = $(" ... "); //adapt to access your file input
var files = myFileInput[0].files ;

// The loop is there to handle file inputs with multiple files
for(var i = 0, c = files.length ; i<c ; i++){
    var blob = new Blob(files[i]);
    var fileAccessName = "myFiles_"+i ; 
    fd.append(fileAccessName, blob, files[i].name);
}

// You can also send simple data along your files
fd.append('otherData', $("...").val());


$.ajax({
    url: ... , //the form's target
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(rep){
        // ...
    }
}
// since we are sending the form trough jQuery, you should also add a ev.preventDefault() to your .submit(function(ev){}) callback
```

Comment: Will try your solution too. Do you have any comments on the relative easier one above? I have upvoted your answer. Is this cross-browser?

Comment: From what I can read on the jQuery doc, .serialize don't handle properly "file" inputs.
http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
"Data from file select elements is not serialized". 

I recognise my answer is more complicated, but it allows you greater control over what you send (for example by checking some values)

You can find cross-browser informations on the MDN - support from IE 10, Opera 12, Chrome 7, FF 4

Comment: I am going through the link you sent. I will go through it, understand it and test it. Any browser issues here? IE 8, for example?

Comment: Unfortunately older versions of browsers (such as IE 8) do not allow high control other files trough JS.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it is technically correct and I do not have a better option. I did find a iframe trick though but have not tested it yet. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you `submit` (meaning the **browser event**) a form, you **aren't using AJAX anymore**.

- Change your button to `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.
- Change your Javascript from `on submit ...` on a form element to `on click ...` on the button.
- Give your `<input>`s each a name.
- Add a `success()` and `failure()` callback to alert the user that it worked or failed (and for your own debugging).

### HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input name="theText" id="theText" type="text" />
     <input name="theFile" id="theFile" type="file" />
     <input type="button" name="send" id="send" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

### jQuery

```
var serData = $('#uploadForm').serialize();

$('#send').on('click', function(e) {
    uploadPromise = $.ajax({
        url: 'upload1.php',  
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'POST',
        data: serData,
        success: function() {
            alert('It worked.');
        },
        failure: function(xhr, res, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(res);
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: And this is cross-browser? Very simple to understand indeed. I have upvoted it for now. Will certainly accept the answer after trying it out and seeing what else is coming. Strange that all the other posts on this subject make it look so complicated.

Comment: As long as you're using a version of jQuery lower than 2.x, yes cross-browser is the name of the game.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any thoughts on formdata route as posted below? I think others will find this info useful too.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to add a `contentType: '...'` to match what it is you expect the file to be.

Comment: @Samir yes FormData is a nice new addition to XMLHTTP2 I would utilize that.  Good answer by that user.

Comment: But older browser support is lacking.

Comment: Very true.  It would be a trade off.  I believe this code I have will need some work as the file will not be serialized and may need a separate AJAX call.

Comment: I tried your code. You are right. The same problem as I had with the type submit button. File does not get serialized. So, before formData one could not do file upload through AJAX? Thats not true, I think. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'll continue researching it cuz there's gotta be something staring us in the face that we just haven't remembered.